# Delete items from nested lists which contains a specific string

Tags: r, list, null, nested, subset

I would like to delete nested items of a R list that contain the string `available`. However, I need to keep the list size (i.e. `NULL` if all items deleted). The below code generate a possible input from which all items should be removed:

```
nested.list <- list()
for(lop in 1:4){
nested.list[[lop]] <- c("available","available")}
```

The expected output is:

```
for(lop in 1:4){
nested.list.out[lop] <- list(NULL)}
```

However, if the item is other than `available`, it should be kept. Let's assume the following input:

```
nested.list[[1]][[2]] <- "hold"
```

The expected output would be:

```
nested.list.out[[1]] <- "hold"
```

It is important to highlight that the string `hold` is only to exemplify. In my real data-set, each item of each nested list can have random strings and should all be kept in my output. Any idea to do it wisely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `lapply` to loop over the list. On each iteration remove all `available` strings and return `NULL` if a resulting vector is empty.

```
nested.list.out <- lapply(nested.list, function(x) {
    x <- x[x != "available"]  # Remove "available" from vector
    if (length(x) < 1){
        # Here resulting vector is empty, so return NULL
        return(NULL)
    } else {
        return(x)
    }
})
```